# Type D Visa for Denmark (Flight Ticket Booking)

Tags: visas, work, permits

I Received a work permit in Denmark for 70 days and the embassy gave me a type D visa for Denmark valid for 60 days but after entering Denmark i receive a work permit for 70 days.
The question is how will i book my flight tickets for Denmark? should i book for 60 days or 70 days? I'm kind of confused here.
Thank you.